# Someone Activated My Playstation as Their Primary

Tags: ps4

i contact sony and they say that they do nothing for me ! and i must wait 6 months to deactive all consoles that connect to my psn account.
after 6 month the other console that using my account will be baned or just dissconnect from my psn account ? if he will be baned witch ban ? (Console or his psn account)

Comment: @Aaron, that one is the duplicate. This is the original.

Comment: @DJPirtu, I completely agree. I had already warned OP on their other question about posting future duplicates like this.